# Debugger always throws error on second procedure

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm, subroutine

I am trying to debug my program so I can work through a HW problem. The HW problem is not relevant to the issue as I tested it with 2 seperate procedures.

Essentially when I am trying to debug I can set a breakpoint on the first procedure and it will work fine.

The breakpoint on the second procedure will through an error.

The code compiles just fine.

The code works fine with just one procedure and I have tested basic procedures.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
    myString BYTE "Hello World",0dh,0ah

.code
main proc

    ;------DigitValue2ASCII-----
DigitValue2ASCII proc
    mov eax, 0000h
    mov edx, 0ch 
    mov al, 00h
    cmp dl, 0ah
    jae letter
    cmp dl, 0ah
    jb number
    letter: add dl, 37h
    jmp final
    number: add dl, 30h
    final: mov al, dl
    call writechar

    mov eax, 0000h
    mov edx, 09h
    mov al, 00h
    cmp dl, 0ah
    jae letter1
    cmp dl, 0ah
    jb number1
    letter1: add dl, 37h
    jmp final1
    number1: add dl, 30h
    final1: mov al, dl
    call writechar

    ret
DigitValue2ASCII endp

WriteHexByte proc
    mov eax, 00h
    ret
WriteHexByte endp



call DigitValue2ASCII   


invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

The error

````
'Project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x2cd0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4f7c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x13a4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[18384] Project.exe' has exited with code 57 (0x39).```
````

Comment: `myString` is missing a `,0` terminating 0 byte to be an implicit-length C string.  (besides the problem you found of putting your other functions inside of `main`...)

Answer (score 0):

I had to move the procedures below `main endp` instead of in between `main proc` and `main endp`